# Add Authorization Header on Http Post

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, oauth, header

Is it possible to add authorization Header on Http Post,
I want to use OAuth Providers in my MVC project, there i want to set my secret token to Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.
Initially when user clicks on login, send a ajax request to Authorization server(OAuth Bearer) with the data - granttype=password&username=xxx&password=yyy

On the success, store the generated token in localstorage
Authorization header needs to be set from client side when making a request to webapi or mvc.
Authorization: Bearer generatedbearertokenvalue

You need to decorate the controller/action with [Authorize] attribute

Comment: how to send generatedbearertokenvalue in httppost

Comment: You can send the accesstoken either in get or post request. All you need to do is add Authorization header before sending the request.I have used fiddler test your scenario(post type) and i get back the data for the request. eg.User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49783
Content-Length: 51
Authorization: Bearer A4_ImVUeCMjRqPpeYrt0UBiks9QbDr6rZTnC0yYPYlFlTnDGRbWhPHvl

Comment: i need code for adding Authorization header before sending the request

Comment: for making request via jquery. use this code - $.ajax({
        url: urlpath,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"        
    });